# Keras model do not work with ValueError: Layer #0 expects 0 weight(s), but the saved weights have 6 element(s)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
Using TensorFlow backend.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "checkmodel.py", line 93, in <module>
    loaded_model.load_weights("./model/model.h5", by_name = True)
  File "/home/hjkim/.conda/envs/hjkim/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 492, in load_wrapper
    return load_function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hjkim/.conda/envs/hjkim/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1227, in load_weights
    reshape=reshape)
  File "/home/hjkim/.conda/envs/hjkim/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 1309, in load_weights_from_hdf5_group_by_name
    ' element(s).')
ValueError: Layer #0 (named "bidirectional_1") expects 0 weight(s), but the saved weights have 6 element(s).
```

Above is the Error I received.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(400, input_shape = (20, 75), return_sequences = True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(400, return_sequences = True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(400, return_sequences = False)))
model.add(Dense(34, activation = 'softmax'))
adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = adam, metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

And this is the code used to build model.

I've made model.json file and model.h5 file from this model, and saved trained model.
Below is the code I've tried.

```
json_file = open("./model/model.json", "r")
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)

loaded_model.load_weights("./model/model.h5", by_name = True)
loaded_model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = "adam", metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

I was using tensorflow version 1.12.0, keras 2.2.4, and I updated them to 1.15.0, 2.3.1 now, but the same error come out.

Comment: You have received above because model was saved in Keras and then tried to load on different versions of Keras/Tensorflow. To fix your issue, can you try to save and load using the same version of keras/tensorflow. Thanks!

Comment: Hi did you find a solution for this ? I too have a similar error ValueError: Layer #81 (named "conv_preds" in the current model) was found to correspond to layer conv_preds in the save file. However the new layer conv_preds expects 1 weights, but the saved weights have 2 elements.